# bash: assign "key --> value" in new array based on old array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array made of:

```
old_array=("color" "red" "shape" "circle" "vote" "10")
```

(alternating key/values)

I need to build a new_array so that:

```
echo $new_array[color]
red

echo $new_array[shape]
circle
```

and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need bash's associative arrays.

First, declare the variable as an `Associative Array` with `declare -A`:

```
declare -A new_array
```

Then set values in the array like you would do with regular arrays:

```
new_array[color]="red"
```

---

You can convert your `old_array` to `new_array` like this:

```
old_array=("color" "red" "shape" "circle" "vote" "10")
declare -A new_array
for (( i = 0; i < ${#old_array[*]}; i += 2 )); do
    key=${old_array[i]}
    value=${old_array[i+1]}
    new_array[$key]=$value
done
```

You can also write new_array directly:

```
declare -A new_array=([color]=red [shape]=circle [vote]=10)
```